# Overlapping divs with the first element in front

Tags: html, css

How can I have 4 images where the first image has the highest z-index, and the next the second highest (i'm also open to other suggestions as to how to accomplish this)? Basically reverse the following depth?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4678rzq5/2/)

```css
img {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: -40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `z-index` as expected, you'll need to set the `<img>` position to **relative**.

Also the `nth-child` has to be of set to the `<img>` tag

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
img {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div img:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
div img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}
div img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}div img:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/000">
</div>
```

Comment: css would be way better if you could do some type of increment count so you only had to type out the rule for n-th child once.

Comment: Yes, JS could be a solution for this, but maybe an overkill for only 4 images. I would consider a dinamics solution if the images are inserted in a dinamics way.

Comment: Haha no need. I upvoted the answer. Just me rambling about css.

Comment: Thanks, The thing is css already got a counter. But you can only use the value as a content. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)